# Weird black patch in my renders

Tags: modeling

This is only in my renders, but there is this black patch at the bottom left. I've tried hiding everything and nothing seems to fix it. Also the left window edge looks much thicker than the right one even while the glass part and the outer parts are the exact same size (this problem also shows in viewport.

https://prnt.sc/UKRcBeaalSMy

Blend file is here because its over 30 mb
https://www.mediafire.com/file/o65pzcj3cgsxoae/Train_Window.blend/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Disable in Renders this plane

[image]

To fix the minor glass distortion:

1. To identify the cause of the problems open *Overlays* dialog from the 3D viewport header and tick the box across *Face orientation*
2. Select the window mesh and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter Edit Mode
3. <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals outside

Comment: oh wow thank you so much this has helped me so much and has even fixed a problem in one other scene.

Comment: @arel256 you're welcome =)